# Opening a CSV file in Python, getting IOError

Tags: python, csv

I've done this 100 times, but for some reason this is breaking...can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Screen shot of the directory - http://cl.ly/image/2K1P1J0m1X2B

Code:

```
csv_file = open('10_13_outbounds.csv','rU')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
return csv_reader
```

Getting this error:

```
IOError: 2, 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Well, you're trying to open a file that does not exist! Maybe you mistyped the name, are in a different directory or someone has (re)moved it earlier?

Comment: How are you running your Python script?

Comment: @hochl Thats what I don't get. Bot the .csv file AND the python script are in the same directory.

Comment: Actually I suspect `'10_13_outbounds.csv.csv'` would work.  It looks like you have extension of known types hidden (the default) in Windows Explorer (Folder Options)

Comment: @JasonSperske just running it in TextMate

Comment: The other alternative is that you are running the Python script in a different directory

Comment: @JasonSperske damnit, that was it. good catch. Removed the .csv in the filename and it ran

Comment: It doesn't matter what directory the Python script is in, it matters what directory is the current working directory. There's no guarantee they're the same thing.

Comment: @abarnert what would be the correct way to path it in Python?

Comment: @MorganAllen: I'm not sure I understand that question. If you want your file to be found in the current working directory (whatever that is), you're doing the right thing. If you want it to be alongside your script, you probably want `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1]), filename)`. But if this is anything other than a quick&dirty one-shot script, you probably don't want either; you want to create a `setuptools` package and use the `pkg_resources` API, or you want to take the path as a command-line argument instead of hardcoding it. (Without knowing what the data are, it's hard to say.)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, based on the screenshot: [image]

It appears that `'10_13_outbounds.csv.csv'` would work. It looks like you have extension of known types hidden (the default) in Windows Explorer (Folder Options)